# Two word Latin phrase for the community service of an upper class (i.e. kings/royals)?

Tags: phrase-requests

This phrase is reserved for when a member of a wealthier class feels obligated (out of pity/sympathy/equity) to participate in some form of community service for a lower class.

Help!

Comment: French: Noblesse Oblige. That was the one I was looking for. Thx!

Comment: This is an *English* language site, I am voting to close as off-topic as this is looking for a Latin translation.

Comment: @Skooba - OP is not looking for a translation but for an expression of Latin origin  which is used in English, so it is about the English language.

Answer (score 4):

***[Noblesse oblige](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/noblesse-oblige):***

> the moral obligation of those of high birth, powerful social position, etc., to act with honor, kindliness, generosity, etc. (Random House Dictionary)

also:

> the idea that someone with power and influence should use their social position to help other people. (Cambridge Dictionary)

The French expression entered the English language in the first half of the 19th century:

> French phrase noblesse oblige "privilege entails responsibility" is attested in English first in 1837. (Etymonline)

probably from the translation of  “[Le Lys dans la Vallée](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Lys_dans_la_vall%C3%A9e)”, written in 1835 and published in 1836 by  Honoré de Balzac where:

> he recommends certain standards of behaviour to a young man, concluding: *"Everything I have just told you can be summarized by an old word: noblesse oblige!*" His advice had included comments like "others will respect you for detesting people who have done detestable things."